# Elevation profile extraction to excel using ArcGIS from DEM in a tiff format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, elevation

I have an SRTM image in .tiff format downloaded from USGS website and I want to extract elevation along a path to a Excel file in the form of distance vs elevation or lat,long. vs elevation. Can anybody tell me how can I do this in ArcGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). We utilize a "Focused question / Best answer" model here. Instead of telling us what you need to do, please tell us what you have done, and what problem you have encountered.  What steps did your research indicate were necessary? What have you tried? Please **edit** the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ['Construct Points...'](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-new-points-along-a-line.htm) tool in the Editor menu to place points along your line at specified intervals or based on m-values then extract values from the SRTM image to points [(Spatial Analyst Tools/Extraction/Extract Values to Points)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm). You could build your Excel spreadsheet from the output table.